# Intersection of directed random walks

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm kinda worn out working on this seemingly classical question. I appreciate immensely any kind of help.
**Problem**
Let $S^{(1)}, S^{(2)}, S^{(3)}$ be three independent simple symmetric random walks in $\mathbb{Z}$, starting from the origin.
How can we prove the following sequence of random variables converges in law?

$$H_N= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{S^{(1)}_n=S^{(2)}_n} +\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{S^{(2)}_n=S^{(3)}_n}+\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{S^{(3)}_n=S^{(1)}_n} \right) $$

$\square$

**Update 1**
A straightforward observation we have is that:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{S^{(1)}_n=S^{(2)}_n} \right) \right) \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}( \sqrt{2}\max_{ 0 \le t \le 1} B_t)$$

**Update 2** There is some "workaround"(very tedious) using Wiener chaos, but not what I'm looking for.